How to uninstall Adobe Photoshop without login?
I can't believe it. I want to get rid of Photoshop that is installed on a Windows 11 and it asks me to log in without any options to skip it when I attempt to uninstall it from the Windows app window.

This seems outrageous and unprecedented to me.
How to uninstall it without logging in?

Adobe does this to mark your pc as unlicensed. If you force the uninstall as you did, to adobe you still consume the license and you cannot install it on another pc without going through a lot of hoops first. If you never activated with an account, then all is fine.

I could get rid of it by first using this tool to uninstall crate suite https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/help/uninstall-creative-cloud-desktop-app.html and after that normal uninstallation worked.
